# Auto executing project on Eclipse start

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to set auto execution of any project on boot in Eclipse Java? I have a round-a-clock running computer.

Sometimes there are problems with electricity and computer restarts itself.

I added Eclipse into list of autorun programs. When Eclipse starts I want my project should been executed itself automatically.

Is there are any way to make it?

Comment: No there isn't. Running programs from within Eclipse is only intended to be used for testing. If you have something you want to run all the time you should export it as a runnable jar (assuming this is Java) and run that.

Comment: [Eclipse Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) has a _LaunchTask_: see [Eclipse bug 438697](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438697)